# Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I wanted to install some R package in a cluster (with the specific version) to do my analysis, this are my code

```r
devtools::install_version("lmerTest", version = "3.1-2",repo = "https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source")   
library(lmerTest)
```

But I get an error message

```r
Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  (converted from warning) installation of package 'Rcpp' had non-zero exit stat
us
Execution halted
```

can anybody guide me, what should I do?

---

Code from a comment:

this is my code for instalation

```
options(warn=0, error=NULL)
library(devtools)
library("Rcpp")
library(remote) 
library("dplyr") 
library(lsmeans) 
devtools::install_version("lme4", version = "1.1-23",repo = "lib.ugent.be/CRAN", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL)) 
library(lme4) # 1.1-23 
devtools::install_version("lmerTest", version = "3.1-2",repo = "lib.ugent.be/CRAN", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",
  options(warn=0, error=NULL,(install.packages.compile.from.source = "no")))
#dependencies=TRUE 
library(lmerTest)
```

```
this is the error message which i have in cluster



    " #devtools::install_version("lme4", version = "1.1-23",repo = "https://lib.ugen
    t.be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL,(in
    stall.packages.compile.from.source = "no")))
    > devtools::install_version("lme4", version = "1.1-23",repo = "https://lib.ugent
    .be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL))
    Downloading package from url: https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-23.
    tar.gz
    Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
      'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
    Execution halted "
```

Comment: It shows an error about installing the `Rcpp` package. What happens if you try to install it with `install.packages("Rcpp")`? Further, it looks like it converted a warning to an error, which might be an issue. You may consider hard-coding `Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")` before this, and/or avoid upgrading warnings to errors with `options(warn=1)` (instead of the current value of 2 or larger).

Comment: I made the modification but again i have the error which mentioned.   "Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector"

Comment: That doesn't give me a lot to work with. Can you please [edit] your question and include the command you used and all of the console output?

Comment: Thank you alot, here is my script

Comment: options(warn=0, error=NULL)
library(devtools)
library("Rcpp")
library(remote)
library("dplyr")   #Versi
ibrary(emmeans) 
library(lsmeans) 
devtools::install_version("lme4", version = "1.1-23",repo = "https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL))
library(lme4)  # 1.1-23

devtools::install_version("lmerTest", version = "3.1-2",repo = "https://lib.ugent.be/CRAN/", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source",options(warn=0, error=NULL,(install.packages.compile.from.source = "no")))   #dependencies=TRUE
library(lmerTest)

Comment: Comments are a horrible place for code, please confirm my edit to your question is correct (comments correct, etc). Given this, I don't understand how `options(...)` within `devtools::install_version` is suggested anywhere, there are several things wrong with that call.

Comment: i put the codes in the code section, would you please check here?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122681/codes-to-install-package-on-cluster?noredirect=1#comment111622275_63122681

Comment: You cannot just arbitrarily add `options(...)` to function calls.

Comment: you think this is the only problem with this code ?

Comment: and do you know how should i deal with the error "'arg' must be NULL or a character vector"

Comment: No, and you still haven't provided the console output. While it might be nothing, or not mean much to you, those commands are rarely completely quiet, and they often have clues to the problem in their output. Just try `devtools::install_version("lmerTest", version = "3.1-2",repo = "lib.ugent.be/CRAN", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source")` and copy *all* of the output from this command into your question.